# Libudev as static library?

Tags: nix, nixpkgs

I’m trying to build a static binary that depends on `libudev`.

Unfortunately `nix-env -iA nixpkgs.pkgsStatic.libudev` fails with: `error: p11-kit cannot be used as a static library`.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: libudev is part of systemd so you're actually trying to build a static systemd. Not sure if this still applies, but it seems that static systemd is not possible: https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2014-March/017493.html

Comment: I have a [Nix expression for compiling `libudev` as a static library here](https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/nixcrpkgs/tree/master/pkgs/libudev).   I don't think it will be easy for you to just use it directly, but you could look at the commands I ran and the patches I installed, and do something similar in your nixpkgs-based environment.

Answer (score 0):

On more recent nixpkgs versions you don't get the above error but several compile errors. If you are familiar with static compiling feel free to submit PRs to fix those.